# The relation of two integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, integration, regularization

In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61498/) about the integral 
$$ \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\,\frac{1}{(k^2)^2}e^{ik\cdot\epsilon}=\frac{i}{(4\pi)^2}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon^2},\quad \epsilon\rightarrow 0, \tag{19.43}$$
which is (19.43) on page 660 of Peskin and Shroeder,
Luboš answered as follows.

> That's equivalent simply to $c\int dx/x$. Switch to the Euclidean spacetime, $k_0=ik_4$ where $(k_1,\dots k_4)$ is $k_E$; i.e. analytically continue in $k_0$ (Wick rotation). The integral is
>   $$\int \frac{i\cdot d^4 k_E}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(k_E^2)^2} \exp(-ik_E\cdot \epsilon_E)$$
>   So it's proportional to the Fourier transform of $1/k_E^4$. The original function is $SO(4)$ symmetric, so the Fourier transform must be symmetric as well and depend on $\epsilon^2$ only. Dimensional analysis implies that the result is dimensionless i.e. it must be a combination of a constant and $\ln(\epsilon^2)$. The logarithm is there with a nonzero coefficient so the constant only determines how to take the logarithm: it should properly be written as $\ln(\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)$ for some constant $\epsilon_0$ with the same dimension.

Indeed when $$f(x_E)=\int\frac{d^4p_E}{(2\pi)^4} \tilde{f}(p_E)\,e^{ip_E \cdot x_E}$$ and $\tilde{f}(p_E)=\tilde{f}(M_1 p_E)$, we can show $f(M_2 x_E)=f(x_E)$ by a short calculation, where $M_1,\,M_2$ are orthogonal matrices.
But I'm not sure why the result is proportional to a combination of a constant and $\ln(\epsilon^2)$.
Though using dimensionlessness, $\sum_n c_n (\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)^n$ is also dimensionless.
How can we relate $$\displaystyle \int \frac{i\cdot d^4 k_E}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(k_E^2)^2} \exp(-ik_E\cdot \epsilon_E) $$ with $\int dx/x$ rigorously?

Comment: I asked in comments of [the post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61498/a-four-dimensional-integral-in-peskin-schroeder). I would be sorry if I asked for further help by a comment, so I've posted this question. If this question gets resolved, I probably can comprehend the whole. If it doesn't resolve my whole unsureness, I'll edit and append contents.

Comment: For spherical symmetry in 4D Euclidean space you can replace $d^4k_E$ by $2 \pi^2 k^3 dk$

Comment: After replacing $d^4k_E$ by $2 \pi^2 k^3 dk$, we get$\frac{i}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{\infty} ds\frac{1}{s^2} J_1(s)$. And then ...?

Comment: You may calculate these things if you learn the Schwinger and Feynman parameterizations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization - All the power laws in the integrand disappear, and you can turn the things to an integral over the Schwinger parameters of an integral of a Gaussian. The Gaussian integrals may always be calculated etc. My comment is that it's equivalent to $dx/x$ means that you encounter $dx/x$ as the hardest part in the calculation, or that the process applied to $\int dx/x$ is analogous.

Comment: Just to be sure, my previous comment isn't meant to say that the Schwinger and Feynman parameterizations are the only way how to calculate the integrals. But they're a systemic, industrialized, "straightforward" method to calculate lots of such integrals.

Comment: @Luboš: I thought you meant that we can get $\ln(\epsilon^2)$ from $\int dx/x=\ln x$. "That's equivalent simply to $c\int dx/x$" means "That's equivalent simply to $c\int dxf(x)/x$", and we can get $\ln(\epsilon^2)$ by a carefull calculation like [my answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/299941/130302) or others on the post, right?

Comment: I upvoted your calculation as a good one. Note that you did use the Schwinger parameters in your calculation so that's indeed close to the hint recommended in my comments above. But there are other calculations, even by other people on the page you linked to. There are also general arguments why it has to end up depend on $\ln\epsilon$ etc.

Comment: I've read [your answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61501) again and again. But I still feel obscure about why the result can be generally said to depend on $\ln\epsilon$ before detailed calculations. Why is $\ln(\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)$ eligible for the result, and for example why isn't $\sum_n c_n (\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)^n$ eligible for the result? Would you show?

Comment: @Luboš: Please excuse me for asking frequently. I thought that $\ln(\epsilon^2)+C$ would be the only function as the result of the integral which can be transformed into a function of the dimensionless variable $\epsilon^2 / \epsilon_0^2$. But $C_0 + C_1\epsilon^2+ C_2(\epsilon^2)^2+\cdots=C_0 + C_1\epsilon_0^2(\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)^1+ C_2\epsilon_0^4(\epsilon^2/\epsilon_0^2)^2+\cdots$. Why the result can be generally said to depend on $\ln\epsilon$ before detailed calculations? Would you please show?

Comment: Dear @GotchaP - the calculation is only considered for the limit $\epsilon\to 0$. Because there are no compensating singularities in epsilon, the positive powers of epsilon you talk about are just zero! You may say that all of them are there but they just give zero in the relevant limit. Only the things nonzero or infinite for $\epsilon\to 0$ make sense to be counted. There is no power law singularity. Consider epsilon small and double it. It can be fully compensated by halving $k^\mu$ which doesn't change the measure $d^4 k / (k^2)^2$ at all because $16/16$ cancels.

Comment: So it means that the contribution to the integral from all the finite places, such as $k\sim 1/\epsilon$, just doesn't change by halving $\epsilon$ at all, this part is therefore epsilon-independent. Only the extreme regions $k\to 0$ and $k\to \infty$ may change because we keep cutoffs fixed. So it's enough to calculate the behavior in the extreme IR, UV limits and you may see that those have at most a log dependence on the cutoff which is therefore equivalent to log dependence on epsilon itself.

Comment: Note that without the exponential (phase), the log divergence of $\int d^4k/k^4$ would be both in IR and UV. Due to the oscillating phase, the UV behavior becomes convergent. It's the IR limit $k\to 0$ where the phase starts by 1 and oscillation goes away, that's where one gets the log dependence on the cutoff for k, and that IR dependence must be simply proportional to $\ln(k_{min}/k_c)$ where $k_c$ must be calculated from the parameters of the problem, so it must be $\sim 1/\epsilon$ by dimensional analysis. Almost everything I wrote holds even for a finite $\epsilon$.

Comment: For this reason, the integral has to be $\ln(k_{min}/k_c) = \ln(\epsilon / \epsilon_{cutoff}$  and the effect comes purely from the IR divergence, and that's why anomalies and similar things evaluated here may be considered IR effects.

Comment: @Luboš: Thank you very much! But it'll take a while to understand fully.